# is there a windows vpn client I can manage from code

Tags: c#, windows, vpn

I have a requirement to write scraper that can scrape sites in many different countries from many different countries, such that say, my calls would appear to come from a server in Italy or Belgium.

I cannot find a VPN provider who's client can be managed from code or the command line on windows.

I know people will say I shouldn't ask about third party services here, but I've been googling this and talking to vendors for a while with no luck. I'm hoping someone might have experience of the same thing.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Appologies to those voting to close my question: is there a more appropriate forum for a question like this?

Comment: *I cannot find a VPN provider who's client can be managed from code or the command line* - hm. OpenVPN? Pretty much command line

Comment: And Windows itself has VPN networking which can be controlled through code, WMI, group policies etc. This question though asks for a *VPN service*, not how to control the VPN client

Comment: `is there a more appropriate forum for a question like this?` What you *want*, is buy a VPN service subscription that lands you in one country or another. That's market research. Quora would be a better option than any of the StackExchange sites, although in the end you may have to just search for providers in all the countries you want to target.

Comment: @EugeneSh. With OpenVPN I think I have to set up my own VPN altogether - unless I'm wrong -  which is more work than I'm after. Ideally I need some kind of API control for one of the major vendors clients.

Comment: Well, your question is not clear. There is a limited number of VPN *clients* but unlimited one of VPN *services*. VPN cients can work with variety of services. So pick a service and check which client is able to work with it.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, but your response gets to the heart of my issue - I cannot find a service that I can control with a client I can control. I feel sure others must have faced the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Proxies for that. Also, if you are Scraping using a GET requests you might try to use the `Accept-Language: <language>` header.